# BridgeIt 1.0 Web-App to Native Camera Component Integration

Tags: ios, html, web-applications, camera

I am attempting to integrate the BridgeIt native camera component into my HTML5 application.  I have the camera integrated and now uploading photos (easy), but I was wondering about how to access photo properties.  My iPhone 5 is set to geotag my camera images.  I want to preserve these characteristics along with other camera settings with the uploaded photo, but I can't see them from the web-application.  Is the location data (and picture data) uploaded as part of the picture, or do I need to use the BridgeIt geomapping component in conjunction with the camera component to get that information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the best approach for this would be to use the standard navigator.geolocation API to geotag through your web application.  (The BridgeIt GeoTrack feature is primarily intended for offline location tracking.)

I have verified that the EXIF data included by the BridgeIt camera does not include the location data (even though Camera.app does) but this is an excellent feature suggestion.

An issue on github has been created:

https://github.com/bridgeit/bridgeit.js/issues/32